# Jointly Sufficient Statistic Question

Tags: lognormal-distribution, sufficient-statistics

So here is a problem I have been working on:
Suppose that survival time $X$ has a lognormal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\theta$ (which are the mean and standard deviation of $\log(X)$, not of $X$ itself). Are $\sum_i X_i$ and $\sum_i X_i^2$ jointly sufficient for the two parameters? If not, what is a pair of jointly sufficient statistics?

My thoughts so far: 
I wrote out a joint pdf for lognormal $X_i$'s. Then, I factored the pdf into two parts: one which contained $X_i$'s and the parameters and one which contained no parameters. As per my current understanding, this means that the statistics are jointly sufficient via the Neyman Factorization Theorem. Yet, here I am confused. How is it that two statistics can be jointly sufficient if I never introduced them into the equation? In other words, what step of my understanding am I overlooking?

Comment: Do you know a pair of sufficient statistics for a sample from a normal distribution?

Comment: Yeah, I think. sum(Xi) and sum((Xi)^2) are jointly sufficient for a sample from a normal distribution. What are you getting at?

Comment: You can use this along with the fact that $\log(X_1), \log(X_2), \ldots, \log(X_n)$ is a sample from a normal distribution to get the sufficient statistics for the log-normal.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment from @dsaxton, since you know that  $\log(X_1), \log(X_2), \ldots, \log(X_n)$ is a sample from a normal distribution, you can use knowledge of the sufficient statistics from for a normal to answer your question. Since the empirical mean and empirical variance are sufficient in that case, you get your sufficient statistics as
$$
\hat{\mu}=\frac1{n} \sum_1^n \log(x_i)
$$ and
$$
\frac1{n-1} \sum_1^n (\log(x_i) - \hat{\mu})^2 
$$